# Doctrine Many to Many relations

Tags: sql, symfony, doctrine, many-to-many

i edit the thread for put more info.

I have the "User" entity and the "Rol" entity, and i am fighting to do work the collection of Roles of a User.

In the User entity i defined:

```
/**
 * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="AppsManantiales\CommonBundle\Entity\Perfil")
 * @JoinTable(name="usuarios_perfiles",
 *      joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="idUsuario", referencedColumnName="idusuario")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="idPerfil", referencedColumnName="idperfil")}
 * )
 */
protected $perfiles;
```

And in the constructor:

```
   public function __construct(){
       $this->perfiles = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
       $this->contacto = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
   }
```

Before the class namespace put:

```
use AppsManantiales\CommonBundle\Entity\Perfil;
```

When execute:

```
php app/console generate:doctrine:entities CommonBundle
```

An error appear:

```
[Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationException]                                                                                  
  [Semantical Error] The annotation "@ManyToMany" in property AppsManantiales\CommonBundle\Entity\Usuario::$perfiles was never impo  
  rted. Did you maybe forget to add a "use" statement for this annotation?
```

Any ideas ?.

Comment: can u show the full entity code? how u `use` mapper?

Comment: oh, I've updated my answer. so it's `Symfony2` :)

Comment: Check if @ManyToMany or @ORM\ManyToMany. The error seems to be that doctrine can not find this specific annotation.

Answer (score 0):

First part: So in this case, u got a relation many-to-many between `Role` entity and `User` entity. First of all, check, r entities correct after generting. Here u can find examples of establishing different realtions: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html && http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/association-mapping.html (the second has more information with examples of Doctrine queries)

Second part of your question: after establishing right relations, select query of your `User` gonna be smth like:

```
$user = $em->createQueryBuilder()
    ->select('u, r')
    ->from('YourBundle:User', 'u')
    ->innerJoin('u.roles', 'r')
    ->where('u.id IN (:ids)')
    ->setParameter('ids', $ids)
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult();
```

And as u guess, u can get roles with the help of your accessor: `$user->getRoles()`

p.s. yes, ofcource if all entities r correct, u can add methods manually.

**EDITED**

Oh sry, I forgot, u use `Symfony2`. So by default in your entities, u got such line:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
```

As u can notice, all annotations u used were with prefix `@ORM\`. exmpls:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
```

So just add prefix `@ORM` and the result:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="AppsManantiales\CommonBundle\Entity\Perfil")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="usuarios_perfiles",
 *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="idUsuario", referencedColumnName="idusuario")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="idPerfil", referencedColumnName="idperfil")}
 * )
 */
```

Comment: thanks for reply. I change the body of thread. With a new problem.